# Internet connection becomes very slow after a while

Tags: windows-7, adsl-router

Since past few days my internet connection isn't working properly.

It becomes very slow after 2-3 minutes. I have to restart the modem after every 2 minutes to use it. 
Nothing seems wrong with my PC.

I haven't recently installed any new application that could be affecting this.

Comment: If this is all the info you can give us you better contact your provider.

Comment: Have you called your internet provider?

Comment: See [12 Tips for Troubleshooting Your Internet Connection](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow/story/262550/12-tips-for-troubleshooting-your-internet-connection) and  
[How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Answer (score 2):

If it is after 2-3 min something is using your connection. So everytime you reset , that connection is also reseted therefore can not use bandwith with full scale for 1-2 min.

So it is either an unvanted program working in your pc OR
Another device is connecting to your modem via wireless.

So close wireless from the modem and try it. 
If does not work , use another pc/laptop via ethernet(do not open wireless)
If problem still goes on call your ISP.